# Displaying Media as a field in Views?

Tags: 7, views, media

I am trying to get Views to display files I have uploaded to my server using the Media module.

My end-goal is to display the 5 most recently uploaded pictures (from any album) in a slideshow on the front page (using Views Slideshow).

My website as a whole will be my personal photography-website when it's complete. The way I have everything set up so far is: I created a new content type for my pictures called *Photos*. Next, I create a new piece of that custom content and upload pictures to it. The organization structure is that, each new piece of *Photos* content behaves like an album--containing a set of images pertaining to it's title.

For example, if I wanted an album specifically dedicated to landscapes, I would create a new *Photos* piece of content, and upload all my images of landscapes to it.

The problem I have right now is, I can get Views to display my custom content type and scroll through it, but because each individual picture is wrapped inside a *Photos* content, the View will display every single image in that album 'per-slide'. How do I get Views to only display the five most recently uploaded Media files? (As opposed to what it's doing right now, displaying the five most recently added *Photos* albums.)

(Using Drupal 7)

Comment: Are you using Media 1.x or File Entity/Media 2.x?

Comment: I'm using Media 7x-1.2 as the 2.x version isn't stable yet.

Comment: Had a hunch you where on 1.x. Just wanted to make sure. Yes, 2.x doesn't have a stable 2.0 yet, but the code is actually in good shape. Thing is that 2.x has a much improved Views support that I believe your needs would benefit from a lot.
From what I understand, your site is not launched yet. If so, giving 2.x a quick test if it works might prove fruitful for you.

Comment: I honestly cannot get the Media 2.x module correctly installed. I disabled the old Media module, and installed File_Entity and Media 2.x. Now different parts of the site such as the content page is throwing up all kinds of errors.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Should have been more clear about performing those test on a separate installation. Upgrade from 1.x to 2.x isn't 100% there yet.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles across this thread, if you upgrade to Media 2.x--it has new options to display your uploaded files as a field in Views.

Comment: Glad to see my somewhat vague first comments didn't put you of from testing 2.x @Matt. And that it in the end proved to be worth it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your field in your view, if you **uncheck the option "Display all values in the same row"** in the **"Multiple field settings"**, each new image in any photo piece of content will be considered as a row. You then will be able to show only the last 5 *images* instead of the last 5 *photo albums*.

Comment: Your solution worked thank you! But after upgrading to Media 2.x it contained new methods that allowed me to directly display a file as a field in a View without using any workarounds!

Answer (score 0):

Gregory has given you a good option.

Another option would be to use [field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) instead of simple image field this way if you want you can add additional information to each image.

And when you create a view of the type field collection you can select the image field and also sort it using the **Field collection item: Revision_id** that way you would be able to show the last fields. Or you can sort with **Field collection item: Field collection item ID**

Comment: Your addition to Gregory's suggestion worked great, just many steps. I would upvote your response as highly helpful if I was at level 15.

Comment: good to know that it helped....... :-)